# How to filter out the elements that meet the requirements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How to filter out the elements {a,b,c} to form a list that meet the requirements 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1? I used Cases, but the result is not a list.

```
sol={{0, 0, 3/2}, {0, 1, 1/2}, {1, 0, 1/2}, {1, 1, -(1/2)}, {0, 3/2, 
  0}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {1, 1/2, 0}, {1, -(1/2), 1}, {3/2, 0, 0}, {1/2, 0, 
  1}, {1/2, 1, 0}, {-(1/2), 1, 1}}

Cases[sol, {a_, b_, c_} -> 
  0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1 :> {a, b, c}]
```

> {False :> {0, 0, 3/2}, True :> {0, 1, 1/2}, True :> {1, 0, 1/2},
> False :> {1, 1, -(1/2)}, False :> {0, 3/2, 0}, True :> {0, 1/2, 1},
> True :> {1, 1/2, 0}, False :> {1, -(1/2), 1}, False :> {3/2, 0, 0},
> True :> {1/2, 0, 1}, True :> {1/2, 1, 0}, False :> {-(1/2), 1, 1}}

Comment: You're using `Cases` blindly, please read the document of `Cases` carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cases[sol , {a_, b_, c_} /; 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 1/2}, {1, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {1, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1}, {1/
>   2, 1, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Syed

Comment: You are most welcome. As an exercise, define `cond=0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1` and then try to use it in the `Cases` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

Select

```
f[{a_,b_,c_}]= 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1;
sol // Select[f]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @AsukaMinato